# Fit width in iOS 8 Today Extensions

Tags: ios, ios8, ios-app-extension, notificationcenter

When I make any iOS 8 Today Extension, there is an empty space on the left of approximately 48px, even if in Interface Builder I place a label on the left side at x=0.

---

[image: on xcode] 
[image: on the simulator]

---

I have seen that some apps, however, use a full-width widget.

---

[image: other apps]

---

How can I achieve something similar?

Thanks!

---

**UPDATE: SOLVED**

I put here the sample code because I guess it will be useful to someone. As suggested by @matteo-lallone, the correct way to do this is:

```
-(UIEdgeInsets)widgetMarginInsetsForProposedMarginInsets:(UIEdgeInsets)defaultMa‌​rginInsets{
return UIEdgeInsetsZero;
}
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Straight from the docs:

> A Today widget created using the Xcode Today template includes Auto
>   Layout constraints for standard margin insets. To get the inset values
>   for your calculations, implement the
>   widgetMarginInsetsForProposedMarginInsets: method.

Source: [App Extension Programming Guide - Today](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Today.html)

Comment: Thank you, as you suggested I added this code and the problem was solved! 
-(UIEdgeInsets)widgetMarginInsetsForProposedMarginInsets:(UIEdgeInsets)defaultMarginInsets{return UIEdgeInsetsZero;}

Comment: Your link is dead. Take this one [NotificationCenter.html](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/NotificationCenter.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH11-SW5)

Comment: Thanks @Felix, it was fine when I posted it! Updated.

Answer (score 23):

I can supplement the swift version

```
func widgetMarginInsetsForProposedMarginInsets(defaultMarginInsets: UIEdgeInsets) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    return UIEdgeInsetsZero
}
```

for oc

```
-(UIEdgeInsets)widgetMarginInsetsForProposedMarginInsets:(UIEdgeInsets)defaultMarginInsets {
    return UIEdgeInsetsZero
}
```

hope it can help someone.