# how to remove leading gap in ios8 Todays Extension

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode6, today-extension

im working on an App that has one Todays Extension functionality, But when i open Todays Extension my App's Extension shows with gap at left side on iPhone , it seems like Extension View shifted 50-60 pixel  right side. so how can i remove this gap.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fit width in iOS 8 Today Extensions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25993986/fit-width-in-ios-8-today-extensions)

Answer (score 8):

Finally i find code to remove gap

**Objective-C**

```
-(UIEdgeInsets)widgetMarginInsetsForProposedMarginInsets:(UIEdgeInsets)defaultMarginInsets{
    return UIEdgeInsetsZero;
}
```

**Swift**

```
func widgetMarginInsetsForProposedMarginInsets(defaultMarginInsets: UIEdgeInsets) -> UIEdgeInsets{
    return UIEdgeInsetsZero
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i had tried this and it works for me

```
-(UIEdgeInsets)widgetMarginInsetsForProposedMarginInsets:(UIEdgeInsets)defaultMarginInsets{
     return UIEdgeInsetsZero;
}
```