# Today View Extension: Remove leading gap in Xcode 6 / Swift

Tags: ios, xcode

How can I remove the gap on the left side of the view?

[image]

I got this solution from: [Fit width in iOS 8 Today Extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25993986/fit-width-in-ios-8-today-extensions)

```
func widgetMarginInsetsForProposedMarginInsets(defaultMarginInsets: UIEdgeInsets) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    return UIEdgeInsetsZero
}
```

When I put it in viewDidLoad nothing happens. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

Putting it outside the viewDidLoad method helped.