# TodayViewController class in iOS Today widget not being read?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8-today-widget, today-extension

My `TodayViewController` class is implemented as follows:

```m
#import "TodayViewController.h"
#import <NotificationCenter/NotificationCenter.h>

@interface TodayViewController () <NCWidgetProviding>

@end

@implementation TodayViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    NSLog(@"yeehaw");
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)widgetPerformUpdateWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(NCUpdateResult))completionHandler {
    // Perform any setup necessary in order to update the view.

    // If an error is encountered, use NCUpdateResultFailed
    // If there's no update required, use NCUpdateResultNoData
    // If there's an update, use NCUpdateResultNewData

    NSLog(@"gitalong");
    completionHandler(NCUpdateResultNewData);
}

- (UIEdgeInsets)widgetMarginInsetsForProposedMarginInsets:(UIEdgeInsets)defaultMarginInsets{
    NSLog(@"yowza!");
    return UIEdgeInsetsZero;
}

@end
```

Basically this is the boilerplate implementation that XCode provides when you create a `Today` target in your app. The only changes I've made are to add some `NSLog()` calls in each of the functions, and to remove the default left margin in the `widgetMarginInsetsForProposedMarginInsets()` function ([as per the method in this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25993986/fit-width-in-ios-8-today-extensions)).

However, when I look at the system log output, none of my `NSLog` statements are being output, and the default left margin has not gone away, so I'm thinking that for some reason, my app is not reading/processing the `TodayViewController` class at all, even though it is otherwise displaying my `MainInterface` storyboard correctly.

Does anyone know why this might be happening?

### UPDATE

A detail I forgot to mention is that the `MainInterface.storyboard` file I was using to implement the interface was copied into this project from another version of the same project. I was able to fix this problem by recreating the entire project from scratch and recreating the interface from scratch as well, so the `MainInterface.storyboard` file I used in the "working" project was the original one generated by XCode. While this strategy fixed my immediate problem, I still don't understand why the `storyboard` file that I imported from another project didn't work. This poses a problem for interface reuse. I'd still like to know how to link an imported `storyboard` file to a custom `ViewController`.